# JSON_EXTRACT How to extract value of a dynamic key

Tags: google-bigquery

The below returns value of key 'a', i.e. "x". This is good if one already knows the key name.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"a":"x", "b":"y"}', "$['a']") as val
```

In my use case, the key name is dynamic. Hence, above wouldn't help. Is there anyway to extract first child element only without mentioning key-name 'a' in standard SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('{"a":"x", "b":"y"}', r'^{"\w":"(\w)",') AS val
```

Answer (score 2):

Mikhail proposes a good compromise to solve this within SQL, but sometimes a regular expression can't parse complex JSON objects.

You could do anything operation within a JSON object by leveraging Javascript with a BigQuery SQL query.

For example:

```
#standardSQL

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION anyJsonOp(json STRING, langs STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """ 
  lang = JSON.parse(json).pull_request.base.repo.language;
  if (langs.split(",").indexOf(lang)>-1) {
    return lang
  }
""";

SELECT anyJsonOp(payload, langs), COUNT(*)
FROM `githubarchive.day.20171010` a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'JavaScript,Java,Python,Ruby' langs) 
WHERE type='PullRequestEvent'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Just in case - following returns the same w/o using JS UDF - SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.language') lang, COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM \`githubarchive.day.20171010\` 
WHERE type='PullRequestEvent' 
GROUP BY 1 
having lang in ('JavaScript','Java','Python','Ruby') 
ORDER BY 2 DESC

Comment: Totally. Was doing a random JS exercise :)